# php list loop div error

Tags: php

New to php. Trying to create a list of images with text in a loop. The script works fine with just , but I want to add a class name  to it so that I can control it with css, but I am getting an error. Seems not to flow cleanly with HTML. Any suggestions?

```
$rs = $conn->Execute("SELECT ProductName, ProductID FROM Products ");
//opens a recordset from the connection object

while (!$rs->EOF) {
  $fv1=$rs->Fields("ProductID");
  $fv2=$rs->Fields("ProductName");
  print "<div class="product-img"> ";
  print "<a href='moredetails.php?productid=$fv1'>";
  print "<img src = \"thumbs/artifact-$fv1.jpg\" alt = \"Artifact-$fv1\"</a><br>";
  print "<a href='moredetails.php?productid=$fv1'>";
  print "$fv2</a><br>";
  print "</div>";
  $rs->MoveNext();
} 
$rs->Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotation will close the php function, try to use a single quotation for your class attr.

```
 print "<div class='product-img'> ";
```

or escape it

```
print "<div class=\"product-img\"> ";
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Still have to remember all of the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 print "<div class="product-img"> ";
```

to

```
print "<div class=\"product-img\"> ";
```

Comment: or even easier print '<div class="product-img"> ';

Comment: Indeed. And there are apostrophes after href= I am not sure if the HTML output will validate with the W3C validator.

Comment: single(apostrophes) and double quotes are perfectly valid for the html